# sharepoint 2010 adding columns to a listview (not the list, though)

Tags: sharepoint, xslt

I need to add columns to a listview, but they can't be stored in the list (they are just calculated based on values from the list.  And, they involve 'today' which can't be stored in sharepoint lists).

I opened the page in designer, selected "Customize XSLT" then "Customize Entire View", and it opens the XSLT code for the listview.  To display 5 columns from my list, this XSLT is 2400 lines of code.  Seriously.

So, since I am staring at 2400 lines of code to display 5 columns, I'm guessing that writing my own XSLT to add a column based on 2 other columns is not the right way.

Does anyone have any other ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A lot of the 2400 lines are boilerplate - you won't have to write thousands of lines for your new columns and SPD helps (mostly)

For inspiration see this series (click on link at bottom to see all 20 odd articles in the series)

[EUSP - Data View Web Part the basics](http://www.endusersharepoint.com/2009/05/08/new-article-series-laura-rogers-on-data-view-web-part-basics/)